# Extract specific cell data from Interactive table - Oracle-APEX

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have an item P0_ITEM, I want to use a value from a particular cell in an interactive report and assign it to the item P0_ITEM, How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Set static region ID to something like `p1_ir`

Define a dynamic action on click of jQuery selector

```
#p1_ir td
```

Event scope: dynamic

Execute JavaScript code

```
$s('P0_ITEM', $(this.triggeringElement).text());
```